# Get robot position wrt world frame in ROS2-Gazebo Garden

Tags: ros-humble, topic, gz-sim

I'm trying to understand how I can possibly get the global position of a model in a Gazebo simulation through ROS2.

I've seen that Gazebo publishes data to the `/world/<world_name>/pose/info` topic via messages of type `gz.msgs.Pose_V`. Following this, I created a bridge to ROS2 via ros_gz_bridge:

```
ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /world/world_demo/dynamic_pose/info@tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage[gz.msgs.Pose_V
```

(I got the corresponding ROS2 message from the [ros_gz_bridge README](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/blob/ros2/ros_gz_bridge/README.md#example-1a-gazebo-transport-talker-and-ros-2-listener)
Unfortunately, the "translation" is incomplete and in the messages received in ROS2 there's no indication of the entity each portion refers to.
[image]

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to accomplish this at the moment?

I'm using:
ROS2 humble
Gazebo Garden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, in the end that was the right way, but the wrong tool.

To publish global positions the right plugin to use is the **OdometryPublisher** ([docs](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/7/classgz_1_1sim_1_1systems_1_1OdometryPublisher.html)). It works more or less the same way as the PosePublisher, apart from the published messages of course.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER

<strike>Found the solution after struggling some more...</strike>
Scratch that, this publishes

> the transform of its child entities

as [per docs](https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/3.5/classignition_1_1gazebo_1_1systems_1_1PosePublisher.html#details)...

I don't know about the seemingly incomplete conversion of the `/world/<world_name>/pose/`info topic, but I've found out that to get a model position in the world you need to add the **PosePublisher** plugin to the model.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.6">
    <model name="quadcopter">
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>

        <link name="base">
            <pose frame="">0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <!-- ......... -->
        </link>

        <!-- ......... -->

        <plugin
            filename="gz-sim-pose-publisher-system"
            name="gz::sim::systems::PosePublisher">
            <publish_link_pose>true</publish_link_pose>
            <publish_collision_pose>false</publish_collision_pose>
            <publish_visual_pose>false</publish_visual_pose>
            <publish_nested_model_pose>false</publish_nested_model_pose>
        </plugin>

    </model>
</sdf>
```

This will enable a `/model/<model_name>/pose` topic that you can then bridge to ROS2 via **ros_gz_bridge**.